# Picasso not Loading Images from Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have `Fragment` with `ParseQuery` to get `Images` from `parse database`.

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(ParseConstants.CLASS_AROUNDME);
               query.orderByDescending(ParseConstants.KEY_CREATED_AT);
               query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENT_IDS, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
               ob = query.find();

               for (ParseObject feeds : ob) {
                   ParseFile thumb = (ParseFile) feeds.get(ParseConstants.KEY_THUMB);
                   //ParseFile video = (ParseFile) feeds.get("file");
                   ParseFeeds map = new ParseFeeds();
                   //map.setImage(thumb.getUrl());
                  //Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(video.getUrl());
                   map.setThumb(thumb.getUrl());
                   feedsarraylist.add(map);
```

I am passing this `thumb.getUrl()` to my `Adapter` to load it with `Picasso`

```
 public FeedsGridAdapter(Context context, List<ParseFeeds> feedsarraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.feedsarraylist = feedsarraylist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ParseFeeds>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(feedsarraylist);
        Picasso.with(context);
    }

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feeds_image, null);
            // Locate the ImageView in gridview_item.xml
            holder.ThumbView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoThumb);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        } view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Load image into GridView
        Picasso.with(context).load(feedsarraylist.get(position).getThumb()).into(holder.ThumbView);
```

The `images` do not load with `Picasso` into the `ImageView`.

Comment: Why are you always calling `view.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in your getView?

Comment: @MateusGondim have removed it

Comment: have you added the internet permission to your manifest?

Comment: @MateusGondim yes I have added it to the Manifest

Answer (score 1):

When u fetch `image` from `Parse Cloud` that a time parse work on `Thread` so `image` is loaded but into `catch memory` so always use `Picasso Lib` so set its `placeholder` with default `image` like..

```
Picasso.with(mFragment.getActivity()).load(mCardList.get(i).getProfilePictureFiles().get(0).getUrl()).into(image).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

other wise you have added in `arraylist` that a time to in `getter setter` to take `parsefile` object.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if your image is loaded correctly from `feedsarraylist.get(position).getThumb()` with this:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(feedsarraylist.get(position).getThumb())
    .error(R.drawable.error_placeholder_image)
    .into(holder.ThumbView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Log.d(TAG,"onSuccess");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Error ocurred");
                        }
                    });
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Ok this is to check if you have a problem loading your image, what your logcat says